# Search for and highlight texts background using CSS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` containing some text:

```
<div>Some text here</div>
```

I also have a text box where the user will enter a search string.

Is there a `CSS` way to set the `background-color` property for a text string matching a particular keyword entered in the search field?

What I have done currently is to find and replace using JavaScript. I am ready to use jQuery for this.

Comment: do you want to change color on the div or on your textbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this [jQuery plugin called SearchHighlight](http://www.jquery.info/scripts/SearchHighlight/demo_en.html)

Here is the code

**CSS**

```
<style type='text/css'>
 span.hilite {background:yellow}
</style>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script src='SearchHighlight.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function(){
      $('#textBoxId').keyup(function () {
          var val = $(this).val();
          var options = {
              exact:"partial",
              style_name_suffix:false,
              keys:val
          }
          $(document).SearchHighlight(options);
      }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`enter code here`Seems like you need jQuery highlighter plug in

http://mir3z.github.io/jquery.texthighlighter/

jQuery Text Highlighter is a `jQuery` plugin for highlighting text fragments in HTML documents.

**Note:** If you need some assistance in jQuery then refer
http://jquery.com/

Comment: Not sure this is what I want. Can you help me on how to select a text in the div by clicking a button? I checked the docs, but in all I need to select the text using mouse.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is not capable of this. Use a JS solution like you are already doing.

My research is based on data from this question [CSS 3 content selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4561376/1381426)

Answer (score 1):

Using [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) you can try this

**JavaScript code**

```
$("body").highlight(searchTerm);
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight{background-color:yellow}
```

Comment: Do I need to install any plugin for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw Jquery like below:

```js
function highlight(term,text){
  let tags=text.split(term);
  $(tags).each(function(index,value) {
    tags[index]= '<span>'+value+'</span>';
  });

  return tags.join('<span class="bg-warning text-white">'+term+'</span>');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test"></p>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").html(highlight("search","your search term"));
  });
</script>
```